# Closures in JenkinsFile groovy - callbacks or delegate

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to add a callback as a parameter in a Jenkins Groovy script. I think a closure is what I need, but I don't know how to do it. Here is the output I want:

```
enter
hello
exit
```

**JenkinsFile:**

```
def rootDir = pwd()
def tools = load "${rootDir}\\patchBuildTools.groovy"
mainMethod(tools.testCl("hello"))
```

**patchBuildTools.groovy**

```
def mainMethod(Closure test) {
    println "enter"
    test()
    println "exit"
}


def testCl(String message) {
    println message
}
```

This gives me an out put of :

```
hello
enter
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
```

Is it possible to get the call order I want?

**Update - based on the answer**

**JenkinsFile:**

```
def rootDir = pwd()
def tools = load "${rootDir}\\patchBuildTools.groovy"
mainMethod("enter", "exit")
{
  this.testCl("hello")
}
```

**patchBuildTools.groovy**

```
def mainMethod(String msg1, String ms2, Closure test) {
  println msg1
  test()
  println ms2
}



def testCl(String message) {
    println message
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might have misunderstood how closures work - a closure is an anonymous function which you can pass to another function and execute.

Having said that, in your example you are passing the result of `testCl()`, which is a `String`, to `mainMethod()`. This is wrong, because `mainMethod` expects a `Closure` and not a `String` as the passed argument.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is how you could use a `Closure`:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
def rootDir = pwd()
def tools = load "${rootDir}\\patchBuildTools.groovy"
mainMethod() {
    // everything you put here is the closure that will be passed
    // as the argument "body" in the mainMethod() (inside patchBuildTools.groovy)
    echo "hello world from Closure"
}
```

---

**patchBuildTools.groovy**

```
def mainMethod(Closure body) {
    println "enter"
    body() // executes the closure passed with mainMethod() from the Jenkinsfile.
    println "exit"
}
```

---

**Result**

```
enter
hello world from Closure
exit
```